# AbotX : How do you create a parallel crawler that stays on and can be added to at run time from new requests

Tags: web-crawler

I have a `ParallelCrawlerEngine` setup as a singleton and also have an `AlwaysOnSiteToCrawlProvider` set up as a singleton and passed into the ParallelCrawlerEngine.

I can instantiate it and leave it to do nothing ok.
I can then add a site and it will crawl ok.
If I then add another site it will not crawl the second site.

I have looked at the [example](https://abotx.org/Learn/ParallelCrawlerEngine) on the site but it doesn't appear to show how this would work and have new items added to it after initial execution. Using `.AddSitesToCrawl()` adds them to the list but they seems to stay in a purgatory state of not being read.

Looking through the logs I get a 'site completed' message even though a site has not been recrawled

```
[2016-07-11 11:17:18,361] [20 ] [INFO ] - Crawl for domain [http://www.existingSite.com/] completed successfully in [0.0001118] seconds, crawled [361] pages
```

and I get an error if I add a new site

```
[2016-07-11 11:17:33,365] [23 ] [ERROR] - Crawl for domain [http://www.newSite.com/] failed after [0.0066498] seconds, crawled [361] pages
[2016-07-11 11:17:33,365] [23 ] [ERROR] - System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot call DoWork() after AbortAll() or Dispose() have been called.
   at Abot.Util.ThreadManager.DoWork(Action action)
   at Abot.Crawler.WebCrawler.CrawlSite()
   at Abot.Crawler.WebCrawler.Crawl(Uri uri, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
```

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: I still have a few bugs with our current implementation. Opened as an issue against the repo. Currently looking through potential solutions / workarounds. Not yet found a solid way to use it within an MVC app

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: My mistake, yes. I'll see if I can dig the code out later.

Comment: @MossPalmer I know it's 3 years later, but did you ever find that code ;-)

Comment: Ah. This is embarrassing. I'm not with that company anymore so can't grab it for you. Sorry.

Comment: @sjdirect For what it's worth, I'm running into this same scenario today.